# Adjust 3d cursor movement speed?

Tags: 3d-cursor

I have this annoying issue. I am trying to position my 3d cursor with accuracy of about a cm (half inch) but the 3d cursor movement speed is waayyy too fast to get any kind of accuracy. The way I am trying to move it is by going to view tab (top right) on 3d view and dragging one of the 3d cursor axises to move it to wanted location.

Despite me holding shift the cursor moves way too fast to make any kind of accurate positioning. It doesn't even move smoothly but in jumps like I have some kind of grid snapping on. I don't know if I do and how to turn a grid snapping off for it and how to make the speed slower?

Comment: use the operator panel (bottom right of the 3D view) to adjust to the wanted value once the cursor is released.

Comment: You mean place the 3d cursor manually by putting in the coordinates? Doesn't solve the issue which is unusably fast and imprecise 3d cursor movement.